# mod_security not blocking empty useragent requests

Tags: mod-security, useragent

I can't get mod_security to block empty useragent requests. I am not very saavy with it so after searching I found this rule:

```
SecMarker BEGIN_UA_CHECK
SecRule &REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent "@eq 0" \"skipAfter:END_UA_CHECK,phase:2,rev:'1',ver:'OWASP_CRS/2.2.9',maturity:'9',accuracy:'9',t:none,block,msg:'Request Missing a User Agent Header',id:'960009',tag:'OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/MISSING_HEADER_UA',tag:'WASCTC/WASC-21',tag:'OWASP_TOP_10/A7',tag:'PCI/6.5.10',severity:'5',setvar:'tx.msg=%{rule.msg}',setvar:tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.notice_anomaly_score},setvar:tx.%{rule.id}-OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/MISSING_HEADER-%{matched_var_name}=%{matched_var}"
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent "^$" \"phase:2,t:none,block,msg:'Empty User Agent Header',id:'960006',rev:'1',ver:'OWASP_CRS/2.2.9',maturity:'9',accuracy:'9',tag:'OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/MISSING_HEADER_UA',severity:'5',setvar:'tx.msg=%{rule.msg}',setvar:tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.notice_anomaly_score},setvar:tx.%{rule.id}-OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/MISSING_HEADER-%{matched_var_name}=%{matched_var}"
SecMarker END_UA_CHECK
```

In the file located here: /etc/modsecurity/modsecurity_custom_rules.conf

But it just doesn't block the requests...

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is the `SecRuleEngine` directive set to `on` in your config file ?

Comment: Yes it is. Modsecurity is actually working on my VPS for other things like blocking SQL inyections and things like that, but not empty useragent requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved adding the following custom rule:

```
<Location />
# Block empty User-Agents.
SecRule &REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent "@eq 0" \
     "id:'13009',phase:2,t:none,deny,status:406"
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent "^$" \
     "id:'13006',phase:2,t:none,deny,status:406"
</Location>
```

I adapted the rule from here: http://www.outdoorsxch.com/aa/00.html/usr/local/ssl/local/apache/conf/modsec-imh/40_wordpress.conf

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: If you're only interested in HTTP headers then you should use `phase:1`